# Remove sanitizer in php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sanitize

I have an assignment that is to plant security bug and I though of convert back a sanitized input to unsanitized input.

For example:

Convert

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;document.cookie&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;
```

back to

```
<script>alert("document.cookie");</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) for this.

Example:

```
$code = '&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;document.cookie&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;';
echo html_entity_decode($code);
```

The above would print:

```
<script>alert("document.cookie");</script>
```